# I want to know whether the apk generated from titanium is a signed or unsigned apk?

Tags: android, titanium

I am developing android application using titanium developer. I want to know the apk generated from titanium is a signed or unsigned apk ? and also i want to know is it  generated in the debug mode or release mode. These information i need for releasing my app into market.

If its unsigned then how do I sign the application?

If its in debug mode then how do I change into releasing mode?

Answer (score 1):

Anything you build and deploy to an emulator or local device via the "Run on Emulator" and "Run on Device" tabs are signed with a debug key that cannot be distributed via the market.  When you create a key file and use that to package under the "Distribute" tab these are signed with your key and can be distributed through the market.

There are instructions on the android developer site for generating the certificate key file here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Comment: Hi @Tevo i have distributed the app using this default android keystore for titanium. Will there be any issues?

Answer (score 1):

**Verifying apk file is signed**

1) If apk file is not signed when you package for distribution in Titanium Studio, then you cannot install the `yourproject.apk` file in you device. (You can confirm that your apk file is not signed if this occurs)

2) Another way to verify is by using `jarsigner -verify yourproject.apk`

**Signing unsigned apk file**

1) You need to create Key store / password, this video will help you http://vimeo.com/10278960

(The process will appear in middle of the video, go through it)

2) After creating the keystore, run the below command to sign the apk file

`jarsigner -verbose -keystore /path/to/keystore/file PROJECT.apk ALIASNAME`

**EX:**

`jarsigner -verbose -keystore /home/balan/tmp/KeyStore360/android.keystore myproject.apk androidalias`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK apk generated from titanium is not signed. You will have to package the application for it be be signed.

See this video for more clarity [Distributing Your Mobile Application](http://vimeo.com/10278960)